# LuckyBackup with network drive, rsync errors 95 and 23

Tags: linux, rsync, samba, external-hdd

I installed samba on my Raspberry PI (Raspian OS Lite, latest version) to mount an external hdd (ext4, luks) connected via usb to my pi which is mounted and unlocked on boot.

I then mounted the network drive on my Linux Mint Laptop (latest version) and put this in the /etc/fstab (and have credentials in a different file):

```
//ip_of_pi/backup    /home/user/backup    cifs    credentials=file,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,uid=1000    0    0
```

Under Thunar I can view the mounted networkdrive, user permissions are set so that I can edit, create and delete files on my laptop and can see the changes on my pi.

My plan is now to use LuckyBackup to backup of my laptop home folder to the network drive.

I have excluded the mount point of the external drive under advanced settings (as it is mounted inside my home directory), when I run a simulation I get no errors, but when I do the backup I get a lot of the following errors:

```
rsync: [generator] symlink "file_on_external_hdd" -> "file_on_laptop" failed: Operation not supported (95)
```

Obviously with a different file each time, all those files seem to be the ones that have changed since the last backup and that rsync needs to transfer?!
(I did one inital backup over ssh, so I have one backup already on the external drive.)

At the end I get

```
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1338) [sender=3.2.7]
```

Is this a problem with user permissons, or with luks or with something completely different?
I am quite lost.

Thanks in advance for any ideas and help!

Comment: Symlink is not something "native" to CIFS. Maybe you have to enable an option on the server and/or the client? Or see if rsync has other options to work around symlinks?

Comment: See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/798773/symlinks-not-preserved-by-rsync-when-copying-to-cifs-share

Answer (score 0):

Try `rsync -avc <dir> <dir>` Otherwise, exclude symlinks. And Clonezilla might be a better backup solution. For `rsync` to transfer hidden files it needs the wildcards: `.?*` so it doesn't copy everything twice, and the directory above it. Otherwise it won't copy hidden files, so you'll lose your configuration.